# Why CentOS server hanging again and again?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a linux Server, on CentOS 6.2. Recently my server got hanged and I had to reboot it forcefully.

Now it is happenning again and again.

Now the client is asking me the reason? This is what I have already done.

1. Checked all type of logs (syslogs etc.)
2. I have zabbix configured for this server. Nothing there.
3. I created a small script to save the output of top command every 15 min. It shows many httpd process just before hanging. How ever, reinstalling httpd and checking httpd logs didn't helped.
4. Strace httpd didn't help either.

Any other thing that I can do?

Comment: If you don't know...

Comment: Was there something on the console when it hung?

Comment: Without more information (syslog, dmsg,...) it's like reading a glass sphere ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Heavy swapping to disk could be the reason. Check the number of Apache processes being forked.  (ps -aux | grep httpd)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my crystal ball is broken, so I can't magically see what is happening.

But here are some tips on what to do to make sure you can answer the question next time:

- kernel logs and /var/log/{messages,syslog} contain very useful data. Read them.
- Even better: ship those logs to a central place so you still have them when a machine dies
- Graph detailed performance metrics of your server (memory usage, cpu usage etc...) so you know what was overloaded after the fact
- Alert on those metrics so you can *prevent* this from happening

And last but not least: hire a real sysadmin. If the only thing you can think of to look at is apache and mysql logs, your clients need to stop paying you.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Of course, log was not the only thing that I looked, but I mentioned apache/mysql log as I saw lot of apache processes.